# Returning a class from StartActivityForResult in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-contacts, hashset

I started a activity to grab contacts from a list of all the contacts on the phone. Now my issue is how do I return the selected checks correctly from the listview, directly into my Person class. Im not fully understanding the concept of Intents and Activities in general so please bear with me.

Here is how I start the Activity from MainActivity.java

```
static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1;
public void grabthecontacts(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SelectContactsActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the class it calls, Select Contacts Activity

```
    package com.example.android.smsapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class SelectContactsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_contacts);
        populateListView();
        Button SubmitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitbut);

        SubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                registerDoneClick(view);
            }
        });

    }
    ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<Person> checkedlist = new HashSet<>();

    public void populateListView() {
        try {
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                Person allcontacts = new Person(name, phoneNumber);
                list.add(allcontacts);
            }
            phones.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        ListView listview2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactlistview);
        ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter = new myListAdapter();
        listview2.setAdapter(adapter);
        listview2.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        listview2.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    }

    public class myListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {

        public myListAdapter() {
            super(SelectContactsActivity.this, R.layout.da_item, list);
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null) {
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.da_item, parent, false);
            }
            // Find person wot work with
            Person currentperson = list.get(position);

            // Fill the view
            TextView nameboxview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.NameView);
            nameboxview.setText(currentperson.getName());

            TextView numberboxview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.NumberView);
            numberboxview.setText(currentperson.getPhone());
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            cb.setTag(position);

            if (cb.isChecked()) {
                currentperson.setChecked(true);
            }


            return itemView;
        }
    }

    public void registerDoneClick(View view) {
        for (Person allcontacts : list) {
            if(allcontacts.isChecked()) {
                Person human = new Person(allcontacts.getName(), allcontacts.getPhone());
            }
        }
// How do I return human with this activity? or is there another method?
        finish();
    }

}
```

Im completely lost on how to return the values I want as a person, so I can simply do

```
hashsetname.add(human)
```

Any help even with general formatting is greatly appreciated, or any java tips too. Thank you

Comment: How would I do that? and using it would return a person?

Comment: Intent in = new Intent(activity.this,
      activity.class);
    in.putExtra("key", value);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, in);
    finish(); you can pass your values as like i mentioned. and get your values in personactivity onActivityResult()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

First make Person class to Serializable,using

```
public class Person implements Serializable
```

now set ivalue in intent like this,

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result", human);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

get value from intent in onActivityResult method,

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

            Person myObject = (Person) data.getParcelableExtra("result");
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it gives me a error in human and an error for i  ? Is it something Im missing that Im suppose to replace or what? I dont quite understand the .putExtra method even after reading the doc on it.

Comment: `public void registerDoneClick(View view) {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        for (Person allcontacts : list) {
            if(allcontacts.isChecked()) {
                Person human = new Person(allcontacts.getName(), allcontacts.getPhone());
                returnIntent.putExtra("result", human);
            }
        }
// How do I return human with this activity? or is there another method?
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }` Works but when Im returning it on the onActivityResult, i isnt defined

Comment: On the line Person myObject = (Person) i.getParcelableExtra("result"); it cannot resolve i, what is i?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98535/discussion-between-projoh-and-vimal-gajera).

Answer (score 0):

add these two lines before calling `finish();`

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i= new Intent();
i.putExtra("whatever",yourResult); 
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
```